# Texture image becoming slant

Tags: texturing

[image: I have an image and I need to assign it to a particular slide. I have successfully assigned a unique material to all six faces but this image showing tilted doesn't make sense]

I have an image and I need to assign it to a particular slide. I have successfully assigned a unique material to all six faces but this image showing tilted doesn't make sense

The settings I am using are: `Right panel > image mapping > extension > clip`
and `Mapping > Coordinat , Object > cube, Projection > Flat`

I have added an image for clarification. Could anyone please tell me why it's happening.

Comment: I suggest using Coordinat UV and setting a UV-map for the object. I'm sure you will find plenty of tutorials how to put images on objects in blender.